# How to troubleshoot dependency problem with OSGi libraries when doing a PDE build?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, equinox

I'm trying to build a feature product using the latest Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15.0) version and hitting the error `Unresolved requirement` below. I have this same exact issue with Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14.0).

This issue does not occur if using Eclipse Mars (4.5.2).

```
eclipse.buildId=4.15.0.I20200305-0155
java.version=1.8.0_252
java.vendor=Amazon.com Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -verbose -buildfile c:\Users\zoomzoom\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.10.700.v20191228-1214\scripts\productBuild\productBuild.xml
Command-line arguments:  -application org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner -verbose -debug -buildfile c:\Users\zoomzoom\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.pde.build_3.10.700.v20191228-1214\scripts\productBuild\productBuild.xml

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2020-04-25 23:47:13.617
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.runtime [6]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="[3.10.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1780)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1742)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-04-25 23:47:13.625
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.17.100.v20200203-0917.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 2 0 2020-04-25 23:47:13.631
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.runtime [6]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="[3.10.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-04-25 23:47:13.632
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1420)
```

I have tried the following:

1. I've ensured only `org.eclipse.equinox.common` version 3.11 jar file exists on the box. I've put the 3.11 jar files in the same locations of the org.eclipse.core.runtime jar file: C:\Users\zoomzoom.p2\pool\plugins\ and C:\eclipse\eclipse4_15_0\eclipse\plugins
2. I've ensured the start levels on the configuration tab of my .product file are not set, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34966145/1371217) for a question about a similar error.
3. I've ensured the permissions on C:\Users\zoomzoom.p2 is completely open to all users.

How do I troubleshoot this further? Are there utilities that can help me figure out where it's looking for the required libraries?

Edit: Here's a screenshot of the .product file. I've tried both with the recommended start-levels as seen in the screenshot, and with them cleared out. With Eclipse 4.5.2, it built successfully with no start-levels specified, the list was empty.

[image]

Comment: Neither of those locations is where the build should be getting plug-ins from - the Target Platform defines what is used. The x.product file lists what is included in the build, it must list every plugin or feature to be included.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks. The x.product file as it is now would work with an Eclipse 4.5.2 build (equinox.common 3.7). Moving to Eclipse 4.15.0 it now can't find equinox.common 3.11, which is what puzzles me. But I'm still learning about all this (just recently inherted this project and is new to PDE builds.) I'll keep looking...

Comment: There are plenty of changes between 4.5 and 4.15 you can't just use the same product file. Feature based product files may not need many changes, but a plugin based product file will need the plugins list and start levels updated.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks! In the x.product file I've added all recommended start-levels, including `equinox.common`, and this doesn't resolve the error yet. I'm now looking for this "plug-ins list"...

Comment: The Contents tab

Comment: @greg-449 that Contents tab only lets me add "features", and `org.eclipse.equinox.common` isn't one that I could add. From this page https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/06/10/osgi-and-start-levels/, it's shown that an older version of eclipse had a Plug-ins tab for the x.product file, where this plug-in could be added. Strange why they took this tab away.  I added every feature I could add that begin with org.eclipse.equinox, but that didn't help.

Comment: If it shows features you are using a feature based product file. Each feature contains a list of plugins

Comment: @greg-449 thanks, I can see the included plug-ins in each feature by double clicking. The included `org.eclipse.equinox.core.sdk` feature does include the `org.eclipse.equinox.common` version 3.10 plug-in. Apparently that's not enough. I can't edit this feature's plug-ins list either. I'm not sure what my next step is... Any suggestion?

Comment: That is an unusual feature to get equinox.common from, normally it comes from the `org.eclipse.e4.rcp` feature.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks, I do have the `org.eclipse.e4.rcp` feature in the list in the Contents tab, and confirmed it also has `org.eclipse.equinox.common` version 3.10 plugin included. Would this problem have something to do with the start-levels?

Comment: Nothing to do with start levels. Your target platform is not Eclipse 4.15. equinox.common 3.10.xxx is in 4.8 - 4.14

Comment: @greg-449 sorry, that 3.10 was a "typo". I was checking the features' included plug-ins using the eclipse instance version 4.14.0 on my laptop, not the build server. The x.product file does contain this: `<features> ... <feature id="org.eclipse.e4.rcp" installMode="root"/>` which means that feature is being requested. The build server does have eclipse version 4.15.

Comment: I'm sorry but sorting this out requires a detailed examination of the build which is outside of the scope of a SO question. If you aren't already using it switch to [tag:tycho] + [tag:maven] for the build - this is the only supported Eclipse RCP build process these days and can give better diagnostics, see for example the [vogella tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)